# How much of Otome Youkai Zakuro is adapted in the anime

Tags: otome-yokai-zakuro

On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otome_Y%C5%8Dkai_Zakuro), it lists that the manga is still ongoing, with the latest volume released in March 2014. The anime however began airing in October 2010 and I'd assume it was on the works for a while.

After seeing the end of the anime and how things seemed to be resolved, I am wondering how much of the Otome Yōkai Zakuro manga was adapted into the anime? Did it deviate from the manga at any point in order to get a conclusion?

Comment: Actually, according to [Japanese version](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/おとめ妖怪_ざくろ) of the article, there has been 9 tankoubon released, the latest being [volume 9 in March 2014](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81%E5%A6%96%E6%80%AA_%E3%81%96%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8D#.E3.82.B3.E3.83.9F.E3.83.83.E3.82.AF.28.E5.8E.9F.E4.BD.9C.29).

Comment: @nhahtdh i've corrected the latest volume release part. you evidence further strengthens my query as to how much was adapted into the anime and if it at all deviated to achive a conclusion in the anime

Comment: Combining the [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81%E5%A6%96%E6%80%AA_%E3%81%96%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8D#.E5.8E.9F.E4.BD.9C.E3.81.A8.E3.81.AE.E7.9B.B8.E9.81.95.E7.82.B9) and [Yahoo! Chiebukuro](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11167917841), it seems it's until vol.6, then the latter half is anime original. (not yet posted as an answer since I haven't confirmed it)